# Is it possible to see the data partition wise in a kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have start working with Kafka few days ago. I am using Kafka on Windows environments, I want to see the data in each partition of a Kafka topic.

I have a topic called `ExampleTopic` with `replication.factor` set to 3 and 3 partitions. I am able to see the data into the topic but I want to see which messages are going in which partitions.

Please let me know is it possible if yes then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got an GUI based tool to view data in each partition of a topic named kafka tool. 
http://www.kafkatool.com
It’s a tool to manage our kafka cluster. Also provide many features should try.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `--partition` parameter of the Kafka console consumer to specify which partition to consume from:

`bin\windows\kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic ExampleTopic --partition 0`

You can also specify an `--offset` parameter that indicates which offset to start from. If absent, the consumption starts at the end of the partition.

Comment: On 2.10 this gives an error says partition is not a recognized command. In some Other thread , it was suggested to use partitions instead of partition, even that didnt work.

Comment: This console consumer feature has been available for a while and [is still recognized](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.0.1/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/ConsoleConsumer.scala#L200) as of the latest release (2.0.1). Could you please share how you run the command that leads to the error?

Comment: :bin mam$ ./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic my-topic --partition 0
The above is what I tried and I got " 'partition is not available".

Answer (score 1):

Use [`kafkacat`](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat), e.g. :

```
$ kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -t my_topic -C \
-f '\nKey (%K bytes): %k\t\nValue (%S bytes): %s\n\
Timestamp: %T\tPartition: %p\tOffset: %o\n--\n'

Key (1 bytes): 1
Value (79 bytes): {"uid":1,"name":"Cliff","locale":"en_US","address_city":"St Louis","elite":"P"}
Timestamp: 1520618381093        Partition: 0    Offset: 0
```

Comment: I don't think that tool is for windows environment, or may be i am unable to figure it out. Anyways thank you!!!!!

Comment: @RamanMishra:- Can you please tell me how you figure out.? means how to see which message are going in which partitions?

Comment: There is a ui based tool named kafka tool just install it and set up your kafka cluster it will show you all the brokers topic and partitions where you can see the data in each partition. Msg me if you don’t get how to set up.

Comment: Ok.. Thanks for help

Comment: @RamanMishra:- I have create topic:- kafka-topics.bat --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 3 --topic Netflix  Can you please tell What will be my CLUSTERNAME, KAFKA CLUSTER VERSION,CHROOTPATH , BOOTSTRAPSERVER, SASL MECHANISM...?  while setup Kafka Tool

Comment: if you are setting up on local:
cluserName : "anything you want"
version : "the kafka version"
Bootstrapserver: "localhost:9092"
sasl mechanish: plantext (if you don't have any security implemented on cluster)